# Account periodic synchronization preference

Tags: android

How can I add setting for periodic sync under my account in "Accounts & synchronization" in "Data and syncronization" category. Similar preference can be found in HTC News and Stocks accounts preferences. Is it HTC hack or what?

Answer (score 0):

what you´re looking for is the SyncAdapter.
Hava a look at the  [SampleSyncAdapter Sample Project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already have a sync adapter. Now I'm looking for best way to configure it. I can add single preference item "Account setting" that will launch my preference activity, but i want to know is there way to add periodic sync preference directly on account preferences screen.